# linear regression-(gradiend descent vs best fit slope)

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I went through Andrew NG's machine learning tutorial and came across gradient descent in Linear Regression. When I tried to look for same using Python I cam across the youtube tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLGfMGsgP34&index=9&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v

Here best fit slope is used for linear regression. Please suggest when to use which one? Can best fit or similar process be used for higher degree polynomial?Can it be used for mutivariate linear regression?

regards
Souvik Saha Bhowmik

Answer (score 0):

The best fit line you are referring to is also known as normal equation. Its matrix form is: [image: normal equation]

As you can see, in order to compute beta, you'll need to do matrix multiplication and matrix inversion. If your matrix X is very big, this can be computationally expensive. Also, if (X^t*X) happens to be singular, you won't be able to do matrix inversion as well. This happens if there is collinearity in X (that's why if you take a statistic class on linear regression instead of a machine learning class, often you'll hear the teacher emphasizes to remove colinearity in your features before fitting a model).

Gradient descent is a very commonly used optimization technical, it's empirical, computationally cheap, easy to implement and effective. Although gradient descent isn't perfect, in a more complex problem domain, it could suffer problems like stuck in local minimum and it requires us to pick a proper learning rate. But often in those situations, there isn't any closed form solution exist or the closed form solution is too expensive to compute. So for a lot of those situations, gradient descent would be a great candidate. For instance, even in deep learning, one of the most commonly used optimization techniques is a variant of gradient descent (stochastic gradient descent, I think in later of Andrew's class, he talked about minibatch stochastic gradient descent).

A quick summary, gradient descent is a widely used optimization technique which can be applied to many situations, it's something great to know and have in your tool box. This closed form solution is good to know of, but it has its limitations and doesn't scale up to size or more complex problems.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes I also remember Andrew NG mentioning the normal equation as well. But failed to correlate with the best fit slope. Thanks for your explanation.